# Save Angular Form To JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material

I have a Angular form and I am looking to save the data in the form create instances and save the data every time it is submitted. I coded the form and looked at help to create a controller and factory but I am having trouble grasping the concept and implementing a working version.

The goal is I can call back to this data when necessary. Help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <form name="eventForm" ng-submit="addEvent()" ng-model="eventHere">
            <div ng-hide="eventFinish()">
                <h2>First Step</h2>

                <md-input-container layout-fill flex>
                    <md-select name="type" ng-model="eve.id" placeholder="Placeholder here...">
                        <md-option value="optionone">Option 1</md-option>
                        <md-option value="optiontwo">Option 2</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>

                <md-button type="submit" ng-click="eventFinish();">Done</md-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
.controller("EventCtrl", function ($scope, Events) {
    $scope.currentEvent = null;
    $scope.events = Events;
    $scope.setEvent = function (id) {
      $scope.currentEvent = $scope.eve.detail[id];
    };

    $scope.addEvent = function() {
      $scope.events.detail[$scope.eve.id] = $scope.eve;
      delete($scope.eve);
    };
})


.factory("Event", function () {
    var Event = {};
    Event.detail = {
        "Sample": {
            "what": "What Here",
            "when": "When Here",
            "output": "Output here"
        }
    };
    return Event;
})
```

Comment: what do you mean with save the data. save in localstorage ??? save into a backend ???...

Comment: I'm not sure, what do you think is the best way to do it? I was thinking as a file in the folder structure for now. I'd be interested in your approach with a working example!

Comment: Why would someone down vote a question where research was put in, an example was provided, an interest in learning further and genuinely looking for guidance?